# Keras.backend.constant() error (Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (Shape_1:0) to a numpy array)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to create a tensor with constant values. I did this by

```
img_shape = K.shape(ground_truth)
random_val = random.uniform(0,1)
random_tensor = K.constant(random_val,shape = img_shape)
```

I receive an error of

```
NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (Shape_1:0) to a numpy array.
```

My `ground_truth` is a `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor` whose shape is `<tf.Tensor 'Shape_2:0' shape=(3,) dtype=int32>`. Thanks!

Comment: I find it curious that it raises `NotImplementedError`. What version are you using? I'm using Keras 2.2.4, Tensorflow 1.14 and I cannot reproduce your error. It may be possible to achieve what you want by directly interacting with the underlying backend. In your case you can try `tf.convert_to_tensor`. I also can't tell what you're trying to achieve - `img_shape = K.shape(ground_truth)` will give `K.shape(K.shape((3,))) -> K.shape((1,))`. If you wanted to copy the shape of `ground_truth` you can try `K.constant(random_val, shape=ground_truth.shape)`

Comment: While I am still unsure as to why the original error was raised, simply using `K.constant(random_val, shape=ground_truth.shape)` as you mentioned fixed the problem. Thanks!